# Pylons and multiple forms per page

Tags: python, html, forms, pylons

I've got a web page I'm generating with Pylons and the evoque templating tool. I'm trying to generate a page with multiple forms per page (one form is part of a base template that becomes part of every page). I'm having a problem as I seemingly can only get the form element values for one form; whenever I try to get the value from the base template, I get nothing back. Is there a way in Pylons to get a form element from a form by name? I'm using the request.params("variable_name") style that is standard in Pylons.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Doug

Answer (score 1):

You will only get the form values for the form that was posted in the request(ie: whichever submit button the user clicked), that's how html works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (to iterate Tom's answer), HTML is designed to explicitly only allow a single form to be submitted at a time. Plus, forms may **not** be nested, so no confusion possible there.

However, a single form **may** contain multiple submit buttons. So, you may if you really want to organize your page as one big single form, and so submitting will submit all the values each time. You will need to take care then that there are all field names are distinct -- so, not convenient if you have a repetition of "item" forms, in which case it should be a lot cleaner to have a form per item...